# insert in mysql with jsf

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have 2 tables in my data base (participant and feedback). I'm using hibernate, spring and jsf. All works fine. The relation between the 2 tables is one to many. The foreign key (id_participant) is in the feedback table.
The problem that when i do an insert into participant and feeback all is okay, but the foreign key (id_participant) take a null value. Any help please, i wan't that this column take the value of the id_participant of table participant.
Here is my code:

```
</h:panelGrid>
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="4">
<label class="myLabel"> Mail</label><h:inputText value="#{participBean.particip.mail}"/>
<label class="myLabel"> FeedBack</label><h:inputTextarea value="#{participBean.avis.aboutApp}"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

and this is my **managedBean**:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "participBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ParticipBean implements Serializable { 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
ApplicationContext context= new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
ParticipantService ParticipantServ=(ParticipantService) context.getBean("ParticipantService");
AvisService AvisServ=(AvisService) context.getBean("AvisService");


private Participant particip;
private Avis avis;


public Avis getAvis() {
    return avis;
}

public void setAvis(Avis avis) {
    this.avis = avis;
}

public Participant getParticip() {
    return particip;
}

public void setParticip(Participant particip) {
    this.particip = particip;
}


        public ParticipBean() {                 
            //particip=new Participant();
            //avis=new Avis();
            avis=new Avis( null, null,  null, particip);
            particip=new Participant(null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        }


        public void save(){
            ParticipantServ.save(particip);
            AvisServ.save(avis);
            addMessage("Profil ajouté avec succès !");  
            }}
```

Comment: I really hope that this is for learning and not a serious application. You should never create a new instance of the applicationcontext if you need one. You should dependency injection to inject the services. You should only be saving the participant the rest will be taken care of by hibernate. However you don't have any mappings between the objects (in your code) so hibernate will ignore them.

Comment: Yes Deinum, i do this for learning, and i'm beginner on JEE developpement that's why i come to do stupid mistakes :) how can i add mepping between the objects ? you have any example to do this ? Thanks.